# Writing library function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to write library function in postgresql. Is it possible to write such function in .Net or I should use a special language like C to do this. 
could you please show me a nice example or article about this?
thank you so much

Comment: I'm really not sure what you are asking, but um, http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/server-programming.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [PostgreSQL procedural language matrix](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PL_Matrix), there is no support for writing backend functions in .NET.  But maybe one of the other languages listed there will suit you; it doesn't have to be C.